# svg: filtering background image, google chrome

Tags: svg, filter

I am struggling with an svg to blur background under text on Google Chrome  36.0.1985.125 linux. The svg is like

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <filter id="myfilter" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="2" />
            <feBlend in2="blurOut" in="SourceGraphic" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g enable-background="new">
        <text x="10" y="100" stroke="none" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" font-size="24">BACKGROUND</text>
        <text x="20" y="100" stroke="none" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" font-size="26" filter="url(#myfilter)">text</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2o2trpc1/

Thus I would like to blur "BACKGROUND" behind "text", but "text" does not appear at all. Can someone please look at this what I am doing wrong? Where can I check that the browser version supports filtering background image?

thanks a lot,
Balazs

Comment: I am targeting Google Chrome

Comment: This is mostly the same as http://crbug.com/137230, the `BackgroundImage` filter input hasn't yet been implemented in Blink (Chrome/Opera).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to work around the lack of `BackgroundImage`. There are multiple ways to do that, if your code is as simple as the fiddle you posted something like this could work:

```
<body>
    <svg width="500px" height="500px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <filter id="blur" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <text x="10" y="100" stroke="none" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" font-size="24" filter="url(#blur)">BACKGROUND</text>
            <text x="20" y="100" stroke="none" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" font-size="26">text</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2o2trpc1/1/).

Another option is to use `<feImage xlink:href="#background"/>` in the filter, instead of using `BackgroundImage`. This can bring in whatever element you want.

```
<body>
    <svg width="500px" height="500px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <filter id="myfilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feImage xlink:href="#background"/>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" mode="normal" />
            </filter>
            <text id="background" x="10" y="100" stroke="none" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" font-size="24">BACKGROUND</text>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <text x="20" y="100" stroke="none" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" font-size="26" filter="url(#myfilter)">text</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcuxLovx/).

Comment: Thx Erik. Sure I can solve this by explictly bluring the background object, if known. What I would like to achieve though is that neither the filter nor the foreground object know about what is actually in the backround. As I understood that is the point in BackgroundImage. Also, only the part covered by the text bounding box should be blurred, not the entire BACKGROUND object.

It does not seem to be implemented yet - I accept that, will do something different with similar effect, e.g. place a rectangle filled completely white with opacity = 0.6, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrougbf3/)